# In itext7,How to center a paragraph vertically in the background color?

Tags: c#, .net-core, itext7

In itext7, add a paragraph with a background color, when using Chinese character fonts, the paragraph is not centered vertically, and the font that comes with itext7 is centered. How to center a paragraph vertically for both fonts.

```
string dest = "output.pdf";
        using PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

        PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4;
        pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(pageSize);

        Color backgroundColor = ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY;
        var currPage = pdfDoc.AddNewPage();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(currPage);
        pdfCanvas.SaveState()
            .SetFillColor(backgroundColor)
            .Rectangle(0, 0, pageSize.GetWidth(), pageSize.GetHeight())
            .Fill()
            .RestoreState();
        string fontFolder = global::System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
        FontProgramFactory.RegisterFont($"{fontFolder}\\SIMHEI.TTF", "simhei");
        FontProgramFactory.RegisterFont($"{fontFolder}\\msyh.ttc,0", "msyh");
        //var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
        var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("simhei", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, false);
        Paragraph text = new Paragraph("你好Hello, World!A4_Blank_5P").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
        text.SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
        text.SetFont(font);
        var canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, currPage.GetPageSize());
        canvas.ShowTextAligned(text, 34, 760f, 1, TextAlignment.LEFT,  VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0);//There is a noticeable downward shift
        doc.Close();
```

How to center a paragraph vertically in the background color?

Comment: change `TextAlignment.LEFT` to `TextAlignment.Center`?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik ```TextAlignment.LEFT``` This parameter is the one that changes the horizontal position.

Comment: try to calling method named `SetVerticalAlignment` on your paragraph. For example: `text.SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);`

Comment: The result is the same.